# Prometheus client doesn't return custom metrics

Tags: node.js, prometheus

I am trying to implement my own prometheus metric in my Node.js application but I can not figure out why it doesn't return my custom metrics in the `getMetrics()` method as shown in the below class:

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { collectDefaultMetrics, Counter, metric, Registry } from 'prom-client';

@Injectable()
export class PrometheusService {
  private register: Registry;
  private restRequestCounter: Counter;

  constructor() {
    this.register = new Registry();
    collectDefaultMetrics({ register: this.register });

    this.restRequestCounter = new Counter({
      name: 'incoming_rest_request_count',
      help: 'Number of all incoming http requests for this service'
    });
  }

  public incrementHttpRequestCount(): void {
    this.restRequestCounter.inc(1);
  }

  public getMetrics(): metric[] {
    return this.register.getMetricsAsJSON();
  }
}
```

It only returns all the "defaultMetrics". What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
this.register.metrics()
```

Function will be:

```
public getMetrics(): metric[] {
    return this.register.metrics();
}
```

Comment: Saved me!  Thank you!  Easy to get turned around with chaining